# Will Cedar grow new branches to balance itself

Tags: cedar

We had an oak fall down during snow storms and break off most of the branches on one side of one of our cedar trees.
The remaining cedar is leaning to the side with the remaining branches.

Will Cedar grow new branches? Can it rebalance itself?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Maybe not. It is likely the tree will always show some evidence of the damage.

If the tree has at least some small growing branches on the side you want more branches, it may grow them out to some extent.

You might be able to encourage it by carefully trimming the broken parts. A dead tip will tend not to grow. You want to trim back to a fork with some green growth on it.

If the tree was previously vertical but is now leaning, you might be able to straighten it. But it will be a delicate thing that might further damage the roots. You could try attaching some ropes and braces and such, and try to encourage it back. Try not to damage the bark. And if it seems to be busting more roots you should stop.